# how to send a variable from controller to a notification in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, relation

i am making a notification system on pivot table so when i assign a user to a client it send a notification every thing is working fine but the notification doesnt store the correct id of user and client so now i want to get it from the controller that i am saving it . here is my code :
user model :

```
public function clients(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Client','client_user');
}

public function sendClientAddedNotification($client)
{
    $this->notify(new ClientAdded($client,$this));
}
```

client model :

```
public function sellmanlist(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User' , 'client_user','client_id');
}
```

and here is the client controller that i assign sellman to use and enter data to the pivot table :

```
public function assignsellmanSave(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::all();
    $client_list = Client::all();
    $client = Client::with('sellmanlist')->firstOrFail();
    $sellman = $request->input('sellman');
    $client_name = $request->input('client');
    $client->sellmanlist()->attach($sellman,['client_id' =>$client_name]);
    $user_notification = Auth::user();
    $user_notification->sendClientAddedNotification($client->sellmanlist()->sync($sellman));
    return view('admin.client.assign',compact('client_list','user'));
}
```

and finally here is my notification that i want to save the exact client and user id that i enter the database in controller :

```
use Queueable;
protected $client;
protected $user;
/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($client,$user)
{
    $this->client = $client;
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function via($notifiable)
{
        return ['database'];
}

public function toArray($notifiable)
{


 foreach ($this->user->clients as $client){
            $user_assigned_id =$client->pivot->user_id;
            $client_assigned_id =$client->pivot->client_id;
        }
    return [
        'client_id' => $client_assigned_id,
        'user_id' =>  $user_assigned_id,
        'client_name' => 'ASD',
    ];
}
```

and here the notification table migration

```
 Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->morphs('notifiable');
        $table->text('data');
        $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: i use https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail

Comment: no i am storing in database my friend i want to show as notification to user :)

Comment: get it in controller and pass it to `sendClientAddedNotification` and then `ClientAdded` notification,  what do you want to store ?

Comment: can you add your `notifications` table structure, just a screenshot will be fine

Comment: my notification is the standard laravel notification table i will add the migration

Comment: @rkj this line is exacly what i want to save to my notification table     $client->sellmanlist()->attach($sellman,['client_id' =>$client_name]);

Comment: that is statement it attach sellman in sellman list, why do you want to store that. better you store `user_id`  and client_id. better add `notifications` table structure.  i think i have answered you before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176396/discussion-between-rkj-and-farshad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From chat discussion it seems that you want to store client_id and user_id that you get from request. Try this

User model

```
public function clients(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Client','client_user');
}

public function sendClientAddedNotification($clientId, $userId)
{
    $this->notify(new ClientAdded($clientId, $userId));
}
```

Notification class

```
use Queueable;
protected $clientId;
protected $userId;
/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($clientId,$userId)
{
    $this->clientId = $clientId;
    $this->userId = $userId;
}

public function via($notifiable)
{
        return ['database'];
}

public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'user_id' =>  $this->userId,
        'client_name' => 'ASD',
    ];
}
```

Controller code

```
public function assignsellmanSave(Request $request) 
{ 
    $user = User::all(); 
    $client_list = Client::all(); 
    $client = Client::with('sellmanlist')->firstOrFail(); 
    $sellman = $request->input('sellman'); 
    $client_name = $request->input('client'); 
    $client->sellmanlist()->attach($sellman,['client_id' =>$client_name]); 
    $user_notification = Auth::user(); 
    $client->sellmanlist()->sync($sellman);
    $user_notification->sendClientAddedNotification($client_name, $sellman); 
    return view('admin.client.assign',compact('client_list','user')); 
}
```

Hope it will work

Comment: That was exactly what i needed thanks @rkj you helped me aloy